# C++ function to split strings

Tags: c++

I have recently started learning C++ using the book Accelerated C++. The book introduces the following function to split a string up into substrings based on whitespace characters

```
vector<string> split(const string& s)
{
    vector<string> ret;
    typedef string::size_type string_size;
    string_size i = 0;

    while (i != s.size()) {
        // ignore leading blanks
        // invariant: characters in range[original i, current i) are all spaces
        while (i != s.size() && isspace(s[i]))
            ++i;

        // find the end of next word
        string_size j = i;
        // invariant: none of the characters in range [original j, current j) is a space
        while (j != s.size() && !isspace(s[j]))
            j++;

        if (i != j) {
            // copy from s starting at i and taking j-i chars
            ret.push_back(s.substr(i, j - i));
            i = j;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

My goal is to use this function to split strings based on commas. So I changed the `!isspace(s[j])` part into `s[j] != ','` so that the function uses commas to recognise the end of a word. I tried to test the function as follows:

```
int main() {

    string test_string = "this is ,a test ";

    vector<string> test = split(test_string);

    for (vector<string>::const_iterator it = test.begin(); it != test.end(); ++it)
        cout << *it << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile the function in my terminal as follows

```
g++ -o test_split_function test_split_function.cpp
```

I get no errors. When I run the script however, it keeps running and doesn't produce any output in my command line. I don't understand why, since the function that split the string up into words based on whitespace did run on the same string.

**Question:** What am I doing wrong? Is the `s[j] != ','` statement incorrect?

Comment: There's an additional call to `isspace` that you need to change as well.

Comment: Use an IDE and a debugger instead of compiling into a terminal, and you can stop / examine why your code behaves wrongly.

Comment: *I get no errors.* -- Compiling without errors only means that the program contains no syntax errors.  It has nothing to do with whether the program is logically correct or not.  Also, [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two parts where you need to replace the `isspace()` function, one for the `i` loop:

```cpp
while (i != s.size() && s[i]==',')
   ++i;
```

one for the `j` loop:

```cpp
while (j != s.size() && s[j]!=',')
   j++;
```

This will work.

Answer (score -1):

I made some changes in this code. replaced ispace function with `s[j]==','` or `s[j]!=','`
***Check it out***.

```
 #include<bits/stdc++.h>
 using namespace std;

 vector<string> split(const string& s)
 {
 vector<string> ret;
 typedef string::size_type string_size;
 string_size i = 0;

 while (i != s.size()) {
    // ignore leading blanks
    // invariant: characters in range[original i, current i) are all spaces
    while (i != s.size() && s[i]==',')
        ++i;

    // find the end of next word
    string_size j = i;
    // here i changed isspace with s[j]!=','
    while (j != s.size() && s[j]!=',')
        j++;

    if (i != j) {
        // copy from s starting at i and taking j-i chars
        ret.push_back(s.substr(i, j - i));
        i = j;
     }
   }
   return ret;
 }

int main()
{

 string test_string = "this is ,a test ";

 vector<string> test = split(test_string);

 for (vector<string>::const_iterator it = test.begin(); it != test.end(); ++it)
    cout << *it << endl;

 return 0;
}
```